# Kohana 3 get current controller/action/arguments

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

In Kohana 2 you could easily get that information like this:

```
echo router::$controller;
echo router::$method;
echo router::$arguments[0-x];
```

Any idea how that works in Kohana 3?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From inside a controller:

`$this->request->controller`

`$this->request->action`

`$this->request->param('paramname')`

Unlike K2 arguments in K3 are accessed via kays which you define in your routes.

Take for example this url:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')    
    ->defaults(array('controller' => 'welcome', 'action' => 'index'));
```

To access the "id" argument you'd call

`$this->request->param('id')`

You can't access the controller / action arguments from the param() method.

Note, you can also use `Request::instance()` to get the global (or "master") request instance.

For more information see the [K3 guide](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/tutorials.urls)

Comment: Does this mean that for every "action" you have to define a set of keys for each parameter? That sounds like a lot of unnecessary work. I read that simply passing arguments to actions like in **action(arg1, arg2, ...)** is deprecated in K3.1 and will be eliminated in 3.2

Comment: @techexpert Every argument that you want to pass via the uri needs to be defined in the route.  If you're using a lot of parameters then maybe you should be using the query string instead.

Answer (score 25):

Updated answer for **Kohana 3.2**, from the [user guide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing#request-parameters):

```
// From within a controller:
$this->request->action();
$this->request->controller();
$this->request->directory();

// Can be used anywhere:
Request::current()->action();
Request::current()->controller();
Request::current()->directory();
```

Answer (score 3):

For those using Kohana >= 3.1, it might be useful to notice that some properties of the Request object have been converted to methods.

E.g. `Request::controller` is now `Request::controller()` (or `$this->request->controller()` when you're inside a controller).

For more information, I'd like to reference to the Kohana upgrade guide on http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/upgrading